# Hex to address in Event Topics

Tags: web3js, ether, ethers.js

I want to decode this hex to address
Is it possible? (EthersJS or Web3Js)

`0x0000000000000000000000002d4cffc2a90e28d90d3404a83bfd774294a3970a`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you know its an address: it is just 0 padded, remove the padding and you get your address.

for ethersjs you can look at parsing and go from there: https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/utils/abi/interface/#Interface--parsing

for web3js: https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3-eth-abi.html#decodeparameter

```
web3.eth.abi.decodeParameter("address", "0x0000000000000000000000002d4cffc2a90e28d90d3404a83bfd774294a3970a");
```

ethersjs:

```
interface.parseLog( log )
```

that will parse the entire log for you

Answer (score 3):

In ethers, you can use the following:

```
ethers.utils.defaultAbiCoder.decode(['address'], '0x0000000000000000000000002d4cffc2a90e28d90d3404a83bfd774294a3970a')
```